# Choose maximum number in array so that their GCD is > 1

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Question:**

Given an array arr[] with N integers.

What is the maximum number of items that can be chosen from the array so that their GCD is greater than 1?

**Example:**

```
4
30 42 105 1

Answer: 3
```

**Constransts**

```
N <= 10^3
arr[i] <= 10^18
```

**My take:**

```
void solve(int i, int gcd, int chosen){
    if(i > n){
        maximize(res, chosen);
        return;
    }

    solve(i+1, gcd, chosen);

    if(gcd == -1) solve(i+1, arr[i], chosen+1);
    else{
        int newGcd = __gcd(gcd, arr[i]);
        if(newGcd > 1) solve(i+1, newGcd, chosen+1);
    }
}
```

After many tries, my code still clearly got TLE, is there any more optimized solution for this problem?

Comment: What if you factor each number in the array and store the a map with the factor being the key and the value being the count.  Then whichever item in the map has the largest count that is the number you are after?  Or does that not work?  With an unordered map it would be linear.

Comment: Since when is 3 a common divisor of 1?  Are you sure you showed the correct input?

Comment: @paddy  3 is the largest number of items in the input that all share a common divisor larger than 1.   30 42 and 105 all have a common divisor of 3 so 3 is the largest number of items that have a common divisor.  If it were 30 42 104 3 or 30 45 105 2 then it would still be 3 but if it were 30 46 105 3 then the output would only be 2.

Comment: What about something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/iSfB5s_iq  Does it do what you want?

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: @KellyBundy a past contest from my school

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting task you have. I implemented two variants of solutions.

All algorithms that are used in my code are: [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) (through [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)), [Binary Modular Exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method), [Pollard Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm), [Trial Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division), [Fermat Primality Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test).

First variant called `SolveCommon()` iteratively finds all possible unique factors of all numbers by computing pairwise Greatest Common Divisor.

When all possible unique factors are found one can compute count of each unique factor inside each number. Finally maximal count for any factor will be final answer.

Second variant called `SolveFactorize()` finds all factor by doing factorization of each number using three algorithms: Pollard Rho, Trial Division, Fermat Primality Test.

Pollard-Rho factorization algorithm is quite fast, it has time complexity `O(N^(1/4))`, so for 64-bit number it will take around `2^16` iterations. To compare, Trial Division algorithm has complexity of `O(N^(1/2))` which is square times slower than Pollard Rho. So in code below Pollard Rho can handle 64 bit inputs, although not very fast.

First variant `SolveCommon()` is much faster than second `SolveFactorize()`, especially if numbers are quite large, timings are provided in console output after following code.

Code below as an example provides test of random 100 numbers each 20 bit. 64 bit 1000 numbers are too large to handle by `SolveFactorize()` method, but `SolveCommon()` method solves 1000 64-bit numbers within 1-2 seconds.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/dz7fcqK6r)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

#define LN { std::cout << "LN " << __LINE__ << std::endl; }

using u64 = uint64_t;
using u128 = unsigned __int128;

static std::mt19937_64 rng{123}; //{std::random_device{}()};

auto CurTime() {
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

static auto const gtb = CurTime();

double Time() {
    return std::llround(std::chrono::duration_cast<
        std::chrono::duration<double>>(CurTime() - gtb).count() * 1000) / 1000.0;
}

u64 PowMod(u64 a, u64 b, u64 const c) {
    u64 r = 1;
    while (b != 0) {
        if (b & 1)
            r = (u128(r) * a) % c;
        a = (u128(a) * a) % c;
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return r;
}

bool IsFermatPrp(u64 N, size_t ntrials = 24) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test
    if (N <= 10)
        return N == 2 || N == 3 || N == 5 || N == 7;
    for (size_t trial = 0; trial < ntrials; ++trial)
        if (PowMod(rng() % (N - 3) + 2, N - 1, N) != 1)
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool FactorTrialDivision(u64 N, std::vector<u64> & factors, u64 limit = u64(-1)) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division
    if (N <= 1)
        return true;
    while ((N & 1) == 0) {
        factors.push_back(2);
        N >>= 1;
    }
    for (u64 d = 3; d <= limit && d * d <= N; d += 2)
        while (N % d == 0) {
            factors.push_back(d);
            N /= d;
        }
    if (N > 1)
        factors.push_back(N);
    return N == 1;
}

u64 GCD(u64 a, u64 b) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm
    while (b != 0)
        std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a % b);
    return a;
}

bool FactorPollardRho(u64 N, std::vector<u64> & factors) {
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm
    auto f = [N](auto x) -> u64 { return (u128(x + 1) * (x + 1)) % N; };
    auto DiffAbs = [](auto x, auto y){ return x >= y ? x - y : y - x; };

    if (N <= 1)
        return true;

    if (IsFermatPrp(N)) {
        factors.push_back(N);
        return true;
    }

    for (size_t trial = 0; trial < 8; ++trial) {
        u64 x = rng() % (N - 2) + 1;
        size_t total_steps = 0;
        for (size_t cycle = 1;; ++cycle) {
            bool good = true;
            u64 y = x;
            for (u64 i = 0; i < (u64(1) << cycle); ++i) {
                x = f(x);
                ++total_steps;
                u64 const d = GCD(DiffAbs(x, y), N);
                if (d > 1) {
                    if (d == N) {
                        good = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    //std::cout << N << ": " << d << ", " << total_steps << std::endl;
                    if (!FactorPollardRho(d, factors))
                        return false;
                    if (!FactorPollardRho(N / d, factors))
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (!good)
                break;
        }
    }
    factors.push_back(N);
    return false;
}

void Factor(u64 N, std::vector<u64> & factors) {
    if (N <= 1)
        return;
    if (1) {
        FactorTrialDivision(N, factors, 1 << 8);
        N = factors.back();
        factors.pop_back();
    }
    FactorPollardRho(N, factors);
}

size_t SolveFactorize(std::vector<u64> const & nums) {
    std::unordered_map<u64, size_t> cnts;
    std::vector<u64> factors;
    std::set<u64> unique_factors;
    for (auto num: nums) {
        factors.clear();
        Factor(num, factors);
        //std::cout << num << ": "; for (auto f: factors) std::cout << f << " "; std::cout << std::endl;
        unique_factors.clear();
        unique_factors.insert(factors.begin(), factors.end());
        for (auto f: unique_factors)
            ++cnts[f];
    }
    size_t max_cnt = 0;
    for (auto [_, cnt]: cnts)
        max_cnt = std::max(max_cnt, cnt);
    return max_cnt;
}

size_t SolveCommon(std::vector<u64> const & nums) {
    size_t const K = nums.size();
    std::set<u64> cmn(nums.begin(), nums.end()), cmn2, tcmn;
    std::map<u64, bool> used;
    cmn.erase(1);
    while (true) {
        cmn2.clear();
        used.clear();
        for (auto i = cmn.rbegin(); i != cmn.rend(); ++i) {
            auto j = i;
            ++j;
            for (; j != cmn.rend(); ++j) {
                auto gcd = GCD(*i, *j);
                if (gcd != 1) {
                    used[*i] = true;
                    used[*j] = true;
                    cmn2.insert(gcd);
                    cmn2.insert(*i / gcd);
                    cmn2.insert(*j / gcd);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!used[*i])
                tcmn.insert(*i);
        }
        cmn2.erase(1);
        if (cmn2.empty())
            break;
        cmn = cmn2;
    }

    //for (auto c: cmn) std::cout << c << " "; std::cout << std::endl;

    std::unordered_map<u64, size_t> cnts;
    for (auto num: nums)
        for (auto c: tcmn)
            if (num % c == 0)
                ++cnts[c];
    size_t max_cnt = 0;
    for (auto [_, cnt]: cnts)
        max_cnt = std::max(max_cnt, cnt);
    return max_cnt;
}

void TestRandom() {
    size_t const cnt_nums = 1000;
    
    std::vector<u64> nums;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt_nums; ++i) {
        nums.push_back((rng() & ((u64(1) << 20) - 1)) | 1);
        //std::cout << nums.back() << " ";
    }
    //std::cout << std::endl;
    {
        auto tb = Time();
        std::cout << "common    " << SolveCommon(nums) << " time " << (Time() - tb) << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto tb = Time();
        std::cout << "factorize " << SolveFactorize(nums) << " time " << (Time() - tb) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    TestRandom();    
}
```

Output:

```
common    325 time 0.061
factorize 325 time 0.005
```

Comment: Why are you using reverse order in SolveCommon? The only practical implication I see is that the arguments of GCD have a>b, but that could be done in other ways.

Comment: @HansOlsson As you can see I have `if (!used[*i]) tcmn.insert(*i);` so I insert into common only if `used` wasn't filled with true. This `used` can be filled with true by `*j` element, because `*j` is smaller than `*i` always (due to reverse order). If `*j` was bigger (as in direct (non-reverse) order) then `if (!used[*i])` will be always true  which is incorrect for my algorithm. Don't remember right now but it as important for me to not add `*i` to `tcmn` if we met same value `*j` equal to `*i`. If you're really curious why, then I can look into this later.

Comment: I cannot see that it happens as written. You are looking through a triangular part of the (i,j)-matrix, and as long as i and j are iterated in the same order I don't see that you will later get to the same i (even considering the 'break' for j).

Comment: @HansOlsson Alright, then I think reverse order doesn't matter here. It mattered before in previous versions of the code, but later I improved code, did modifications and didn't change the order, just forgot. So it anyway works in both directions then.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to search among all possible prime numbers to find out which prime number can divide most element in the array.

Code:

```
std::vector<int> primeLessEqualThanN(int N) {
    std::vector<int> primes;    
    for (int x = 2; x <= N; ++x) {
        bool isPrime = true;
        for (auto& p : primes) {
            if (x % p == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) primes.push_back(x);
    }
    return primes;
}

int maxNumberGCDGreaterThan1(int N, std::vector<int>& A) {
    int A_MAX = *std::max_element(A.begin(), A.end());  // largest number in A
    std::vector<int> primes = primeLessEqualThanN(std::sqrt(A_MAX)); 

    int max_count = 0;
    for (auto& p : primes) {
        int count = 0;
        for (auto& n : A)
            if (n % p == 0)
                count++;
        max_count = count > max_count ? count : max_count;
    }
    return max_count;
}
```

Note that in this way you cannot find out the value of the GCD, the code is based on that we dont need to know it.

Comment: I think the "primeLessEqualThanN" function won't work because arr[i] is up to 10^9

Comment: @unglinh279  Then the max possible input of "primeLessEqualThanN" is sqrt(10^9), about 32000. I believe it is not a large number. I don't know the time limit of your problem, though.

Comment: @unglinh279 In the question you wrote 10^18. Which one is it?

Comment: my bad, arr[i] is up to 10^18, so sqrt(10^18) is about 10^9, which will get TLE